# Power BI Template creation

Tags: excel, powerbi, data-analysis

Good afternoon. I work for a telecom company, specifically in the Customer Success team. I created a spreadsheet for one of my customers monthly invoice using the raw csv file that our billing system generates. It works fine in excel, but is a bit messy, and my higher ups wanted me to start using power BI. I was able to create a much better looking report in power BI, but i'm running into the issue of recreating the report every month efficiently. In excel, I created a template file, that allows me to copy/past the raw data, and all the slicers and pivot tables are kept and only takes me minutes to send off. I've googled this a few times now and I cannot see a way to do the same thing with power BI, where i add in the csv file, and all the visualizations are kept and just the data is updated. Any help would be appreciated

[Blank Excel Pivots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIWUu.jpg)

[Excel Drop section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVV6P.jpg)

[Filled Pivot Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSE5i.jpg)

[Power BI Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYGkN.jpg)

I tried creating a template via export in Power BI, and that didn't seem to do anything, as it just continues to load the previous data. I also tried importing a new spreadsheet, but couldn't figure out how to get the system to use the new data, rather than the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Power BI go to File - Options and settings - Data source settings
2. You will see the file that you imported in the first place when you set up the report
3. Click on Change Source, browse for the csv of the next month and click okay
4. If the file structure hasn't changed Power BI will update all report pages with the new data

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or use a query like this to load the newest .csv file in a folder:

```
let
    dir = Folder.Contents("c:\temp" ),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dir, each ([Extension] = ".csv")),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date modified", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Contents" = Table.FirstN(#"Sorted Rows",1)[Content]{0},
    #"Imported CSV" = Csv.Document(#"Contents",[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in
    #"Imported CSV"
```

Comment: Fairly sure that table.sort needs a buffer around it to keep the sort order, doesn't it?

Comment: I only see that aggregations, merges, and duplicate removal might not preserve the order. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/commonissues

Comment: I think you're right. I was getting confused by how PQ streams data sometimes. This exact scenario is described in detail here: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2019/12/10/4778/power-query-m-primer-part12-tables-table-think-i

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do, rather than have to change the file location, or use a bit of M code, is to use to [load from folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/folder). This will load all (or just one) the file(s) in a folder location. You can set the folder on your local PC or Onedrive, dump your new file in every month, and click refresh. You'll not have to change the file name it will just load everything in that folder. This is helpful, if you have for example a monthly csv file that you have to load every month with that months data, Jan, Feb, March etc.

[image]

I also recommend using Power Flow to get the csv file from an email or location, delete the contents of the source folder in OneDrive, save the new file in the OneDrive, then process the Power BI Dataset to get the latest data.